# AngularJS creating a directive then uses another directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to create a directive to cut down on the boilerplate code that I'd have to write.

I'm using the angular xeditable directive to allow for inline editing, but when I add the xeditable directive attributes from my directive, it doesn't work.

When I say it doesn't work, I mean usually when I click on the element there is an input box that appears, and right now nothing happens when I click on the element.

```
Glenn.directive('edit', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        template: '{{ content.' + 'ParamData' + '.data }}',
        scope: {
            ParamData: '@edit'
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {     
            element.attr('editable-text', 'content.' + attrs.edit + '.data');
            element.attr('onbeforesave', 'update($data, content.' + attrs.edit +'.id');
        }
    }
});
```

So, my first problem is that the xeditable directive doesn't work because it's inside of mine. I'm new to creating angularjs directives, but am wondering if it could have something to do with the way its being compiled?

My second problem is with the template. If my template just looks like this

```
template: '{{ ParamData }}'
```

Then it outputs the correct data, but I can't make it work without the other pieces to reference the scope data.

Also, here is what the view looks like using the directive

```
<h2 edit="portrait_description_title"></h2>
```

And here is what it would look like if I didn't use a directive to cut down on the boiler code

```
<h1 editable-text="content.portrait_description_title.data" onbeforesave="update($data, content.portrait_description_title.id)">
     {{ content.portrait_description_title.data }}
</h1>
```

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: You'll need to read up on scopes and transclusion. When you specify `scope: {}` you are creating a new scope, this is why you can't access the parent scope. Either don't create a child scope, or pass in the required element like you did with ParamData. Use transclusion to nest the directives (similar to how ng-repeat works, for example).

Comment: Either you would need to recompile the code or (as stated above) use a transclusion and the compiler will make sure to handle the nested directive compilation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to recompile the element after adding those attributes, here is an example:

**Example plunker:** http://plnkr.co/edit/00Lb4A9rVSZuZjkNyn2o?p=preview

```
.directive('edit', function($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    priority: 1000,
    terminal: true, // only compile this directive at first, will compile others later in link function
    template: function (tElement, tAttrs) {
      return '{{ content.' + tAttrs.edit + '.data }}';
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      attrs.$set('editable-text', 'content.' + attrs.edit + '.data');
      attrs.$set('onbeforesave', 'update($data, content.' + attrs.edit + '.id)');
      attrs.$set('edit', null); // remove self to avoid recursion.
      $compile(element)(scope);
    }
  }
});
```

Things to consider:

- remove the isolated scope to simplify things as it seems you would like to do the binding directly to a scope in controller `content.portrait_description_title.data` in the first place.
- `template:` also accept function, this way you can get the `edit` attribute value to construct the template.
- mark as a `terminal` directive and raise `priority`, so that at first run, only this diective (out of others in the same element) will get compiled.
- `attrs.$set()` is useful for adding/removing attributes, use it to add the `editable-text` directive and `onbeforesave`.
- remove the directive itself, i.e. the `edit` attribute, to prevent a recursion after a next compilation.
- use `$compile` service to recompile the element, in order to make `editable-text` and `onbeforesave` works.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Just add another directive inside template of first directive and bind it to scope model that you get from attr. You can also add controller function, and create more models, or logic and bind to directive template.

Also maybe your attributes may not be available on template, than you need to add $watch to your isolated scope model and update another scope model inside controller. That second one model needs to be binded to template. More information about directives you can find on AngularJS docs, but also here is one good article, it can help you:

http://www.sitepoint.com/practical-guide-angularjs-directives-part-two/