# Variable value as directive/controller name inside template (with $compile/$interpolate)?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-template

I am creating a directive in which template I need to use the a scope's variable value as the name of the directive (or alternatively controller) to load.

Say I have a directive widget that has a template called widget.html which looks like:

```
<div class="widget widget.type" {{widget.type}} ng-controller="widget.type">
    <div class="navBar">
        <div ng-include="widget.type + '-t.html'"></div>
    <i class="fa fa-close"></i>
    <hr>
    </div>
    <div ng-include="widget.type + '-f.html'"></div>
</div>
```

Now `widget.type` is not getting evaluated in the first line. It works fine for ng-include. Say `widget.type`'s value is `weather`. The first line should then be **interpolated first** to look like (doesn't matter if class attribute, widget.type-attr or ng-controller is interpolated)

```
<div class="widget" weather>
```

and **then** compiled to include the weather directive.

How can I get **`widget.type` interpolated in the template?**

**Not an option is to use ng-include to load the directive**. I need to use one **common template** for the widget and want to **add/override/extend** the base directive with **additonal functionality/Variables**.

If this is not the way to achieve that, is there a way to **extend a directive** the OOP-way?

[See the plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/xNVFW25IfW8T8A7DwxOD?p=preview)

Comment: Whats the use case of `{{widget.type}}` attribute?

Comment: @RahilWazir widget.type should contain a directive name. It should contain add the directive. Will edit with an example.

Answer (score 0):

You can only place interpolation expressions in text nodes and attribute values. AngularJS evaluates your template by first turning it into DOM and then invoking directive compilation, etc. If you try to place `{{...}}` instead of attribute *name*, you'll just end up with messed-up DOM.

If you really need to replace a whole directive based on `$scope` variable value, you'll need to [create a directive for application of other directives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24898969/angularjs-creating-a-directive-then-uses-another-directive) and do some heavy lifting with `$compile` (you'll have to completely re-compile the template each time the value changes). I'd recommend trying to find other designs solving your situation before attempting this.

For adjusting your template based on element attributes, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27542427/adjusting-directive-template-based-on-element-attributes/27542511#27542511).

Comment: Thanks for that. I tried adding `link: {
      pre: function(scope, element, attrs){
        attrs.$set('ngController', scope.widget.type + 'Ctrl');
      }
    }` to my directive, but the controller isn't hooked up then [(see the plunkr)](http://plnkr.co/edit/xNVFW25IfW8T8A7DwxOD?p=preview). If I try to add `$compile(element)(scope)` after it, weird things happen the 2nd time I add a widget.
Since you recommend another approach: Do you have an idea how I could dynamically add behaviour to the base directive while having a common template?

Comment: That really depends of what you're trying to achieve. Doing just `$attrs.$set('ngController', ...)` cannot work, because Angular creates a map of directives to be compiled long before that happens. Using `$compile` is not so easy. (Read the documentation.) You have to keep your "dead" template somewhere and manually compile it and insert into DOM. Using `$compile` on an already linked live DOM will obviously lead to disaster.